# How Can I export a JavaScript Generated HTML Table to Excel?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, d3.js

I really shot myself in the foot this time.  I'm using JavaScript to build an HTML table on one of my pages. I got everything to work fine but I can't copy this table into Excel like a normal HTML table.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the fact it's a JS-generated table (using d3.js specifically) as when you look at the page source in the web browser, the table is obviously not there except for the few bits that were hard coded into HTML.

My problem is, I need to work with this data in Excel. I use to build these tables using PHP and that was fine but someone suggested I migrate to d3.js and didn't realize I would run into this problem.  For example, if I select the entire table and copy/paste special into Excel in any way it dumps it all into one cell instead of parsing it properly.

I'm kind of stuck in a time crunch to get this data out of the browser and into Excel so rewriting my web page isn't an option.

Idea?

Comment: Can you provide some source code?

Comment: It would take quite a while to simplify it down to an example for this site.  Simple copy/paste seems to work fine in Chrome.  I'll use that for now to meet my deadline and come back to elaborate on my question.

Comment: its fine just do an ajax call to a php page when they push the export to excel button and do it in php.

Comment: Does the result have to be an actual html table? couldn't you just export it to a tab delimited string?

Comment: fun fact: saving an HTML page with just a table in it as table.xls and then double-clicking it opens it in excel as expected.